# Send kafka string message java to start program on other java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Read.java

```
public class Read {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String conn = "db_url";
        String username = "*****";
        String pwd = "*****";
        String sql = "INSERT INTO table (column) values (?)";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.247.36.174:3306");
        props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);
        props.put("linger.ms", 1);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        Producer<String, String> producer = null;

        

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conn, username, pwd);
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("All.log"));) {

            String line = null;
            
                    processMessages(line, br, listparam, ps);
                    break;
                
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error in \n" + ex);
        } finally {
            producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
            String msg = "Done";
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("HelloKafka", msg));
            System.out.println("Sent: " + msg);

        }
        producer.close();

    }

    public static void processMessages(String line, BufferedReader br, List<String> list param, PreparedStatement ps)
            throws Exception {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        message.append(line);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String firstWord = line.split(" ", 2)[0];
            if (listparam.contains(firstWord)) {
                ps.setString(1, message.toString());
                ps.executeUpdate();
                message.setLength(0);
                message.append(line);
            } else {
                message.append("\n" + line);
            }
        }

        if (message.length() > 0) {
            ps.setString(1, message.toString());
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Retrieve.java

```
public class Retrieve {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String conn = "db_url";
        String username = "****";
        String pwd = "****";
        String sql = "SELECT * from table1";
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "ipaddress");
        props.put("group.id", "group-1");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("HelloKafka"));

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                if (record.value().equals("Done")) {
                    try (Connection con = ...;
                        PreparedStatement ps = ....;) {
                        ResultSet rs =.....;
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            String rawData = rs.getString("RawData");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.err.println("Error in \n" + ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to Kafka. can someone tell me which part did I wrong ? I don't know how to use Kafka in java. in ReadLg.java I want to read from the log file and insert it into DB and then when it finished I want to send a message to the RetrieveData.java so it can start. the retrieve data will be run but idle waiting for the message from the ReadLg.java. Is this a bad approach? or the old approach? any suggestions or help on fixing this? I keep getting error can't connect to the IP address
Below is the error message:

```
14:23:00.482 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
14:23:00.482 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:00.532 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:00.583 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:00.633 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:00.683 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:00.733 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:00.784 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:00.834 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:00.885 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:00.935 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:00.985 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:01.036 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:01.086 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:01.137 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:01.187 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:01.238 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:01.289 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:01.339 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:01.389 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:01.439 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
14:23:01.490 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initialize connection to node 10.247.36.174:3306 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
14:23:01.490 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node 10.247.36.174:3306 (id: -1 rack: null)
14:23:02.012 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
14:23:02.012 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
14:23:02.012 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
14:23:02.520 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection with /10.247.36.174 disconnected
java.io.EOFException: null
```

Comment: Print the entire stack-trace please.

Comment: @PrashantPandey you mean the error message? already added:)

Comment: How is `ipadress` your broker adress? That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: the IP address is the database for connection to database right? or not? let me edit it @daniu

Comment: @stephen, `bootstrap.servers` properties value should be address with port of one or list of Kafka Brokers

Comment: @wardziniak pardon me, but do you mean I need to separate the properties into other files? and am I doing correctly sending string using Kafka ? can you suggest me some source where I could learn from the basic so I could improve it my self:)

Comment: @stephen, You have written, that `ipadress` is address to database. But on the other hand you pass it as _connection string_ to Kafka (`bootstrap.servers`), what is wrong. Usually Kafka Broker address is something like: `localhost:9092`, etc. I mean you should set `bootstrap.servers` value properly

Comment: @wardziniak so Kafka using different connections? I thought the connection must the same as the localhost that I used for DB. does my approach in this program already correct?

Comment: @stephen, yes, Each application has its different address, port or protocol. Please check your broker address and port and set in your application

Comment: @wardziniak i keep getting Connection to node -1 could not be established. The broker may not be available. this message. do i need to set broker? I mean what is broker anyway? is it same as the port i set in the bootstrap.server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200642/discussion-between-wardziniak-and-stephen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing: To use Kafka Consumer/Producer at first you have to start Zookeeper and Kafka broker.

For testing or developing purpose you can start it by your own using:

1. documentation: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart_startserver
2. Docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka

If your Kafka is ready you can start using it. You have to rember to set proper value for `bootstrap.server` (for local use it is usually `localhost:9092`)

Comment: do you know the alternative `kafkaConsumer.poll` is deprecated.. is there any recommendation to use, other than using poll?

Comment: @stephen, function `KafkaConsumer::poll(final long timeoutMs)` is deprecated. You should use: `KafkaConsumer::poll(final Duration timeout)`